# xcode - ipa signed for ad hod never appears in test flight

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I want to test the pre-release version of my app before publishing it.

I created the adhod mobileprovision for my iPad and signed the ipa, I saw that
the ad hoc profile was used.

Now when I upload it to itunes connect I cant the the version, so I cant 
send it to any of the testers.

Here is the screenshot:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/hup2rp86wyd373y/Screenshot%202016-04-08%2011.26.51.png?dl=0

I just want to test the app on my ipad before submitting it.

Mirza

Comment: try to upload it again from organization. i face this issue some time i need to upload same ipa 2 or 3 time on iTunesConnect. Or you can also use provisional profile too for test in test-flight. There is no necessary to use adhoc only.

Comment: hmm...thanks but I dont quite understand...you mean upload it few times from xcode to itunes connect?

Comment: that happen some time not all time you dont need to creaet new IPA file use the same just do the upload process again

Comment: are you upload app first time. please check in activity tab is your build in processing mode.?